# Postgresql sorting string_agg

Tags: postgresql

I run the following query `string_agg(DISTINCT grades, '|')`, which executed and outputted my result in this order `01|02|03|04|05|KG|PK`.

How can I rearrange it this way `PK|KG|01|02|03|04|05`?

```
SELECT
      U.CUSTOM_100000001 AS USERID
    , SC.TITLE
    , U.FIRST_NAME
    , U.LAST_NAME
    , string_AGG(DISTINCT SGL.short_name, '|')
FROM
      USERS U
    , COURSE_PERIODS CP
    , SCHOOLS SC
    , school_gradelevels SGL
WHERE
    CP.SCHOOL_ID=SC.ID
        AND
    U.STAFF_ID = CP.TEACHER_ID
        AND
    SGL.SCHOOL_ID = SC.ID
        AND
    CP.SYEAR =2015
        AND
    SGL.short_name in('PK','KG','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08')
        AND
    SC.CUSTOM_327 IN ('0021','0025','0051','0061','0071','0073','0081','0101','0111','0131','0211','0‌​221','0294','0301','0321','0341','0361','0371','0291')
GROUP BY
    U.CUSTOM_100000001, SC.TITLE, U.FIRST_NAME, U.LAST_NAME
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of your query to your question?  ie the entire `SELECT` statement

Comment: SELECT  
U.CUSTOM_100000001 AS USERID,

SC.TITLE,
U.FIRST_NAME,
U.LAST_NAME,
string_AGG(DISTINCT SGL.short_name, '|')


FROM USERS U,
COURSE_PERIODS CP,
SCHOOLS SC,
school_gradelevels SGL

WHERE CP.SCHOOL_ID=SC.ID
AND U.STAFF_ID = CP.TEACHER_ID
AND SGL.SCHOOL_ID = SC.ID


AND CP.SYEAR =2015
and SGL.short_name in('PK','KG','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08')
 AND SC.CUSTOM_327 IN ('0021','0025','0051','0061','0071','0073','0081','0101','0111','0131','0211','0221','0294','0301','0321','0341','0361','0371','0291')

GROUP BY 
U.CUSTOM_100000001,
SC.TITLE,
U.FIRST_NAME,
U.LAST_NAME

Answer (score 4):

It's possible in PostgreSQL 9.0+:

```
SELECT
    string_agg(DISTINCT SGL.short_name
            , '|' ORDER BY
                (substring(SGL.short_name, '^[0-9]+'))::int NULLS FIRST,
                 substring(SGL.short_name, '[^0-9_]+$') DESC)
FROM school_gradelevels SGL;
```

Test example:

```
WITH tbl(grade) AS (
    VALUES
     ('01'), 
     ('02'), 
     ('03'), 
     ('PK'), 
     ('KG') 
)
SELECT grade
FROM tbl
ORDER BY (substring(grade, '^[0-9]+'))::int NULLS FIRST, substring(grade, '[^0-9_]+$') DESC;
```

Result:

```
 grade
-------
 PK
 KG
 01
 02
 03
(5 rows)
```

[Aggregate Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

Comment: GETTING THIS ERROR  in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list LINE 13

Comment: Error message is more or less self-explanatory. Can you create http://sqlfiddle.com/ for your table schema/data?